# Exponential vs Polynomial growth

Tags: exponentiation

May somebody give me a prove why $n^{r} < c^{n}$  when $r \in R_{>0}$, $ c \in R_{>1}$ and $ n    \in N$ (for all $n$ at some point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is, given real $\beta > 0,$ 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{e^{\beta x}}{x} ?$$

It is not necessary to use L'Hospital, it is enough to see that the first derivative is
$$  \frac{\left( \beta x - 1 \right) e^{\beta x}}{x^2} $$ and the second is
$$  \frac{\left( \beta^2 x^2 - 2 \beta x +2 \right) e^{\beta x}}{x^3}. $$
That is, for $x > 0,$ the second derivative is strictly positive. The original function begins with a vertical asymptote at $x=0,$ descends to a minimum at $x = 1 / \beta,$ but then increases without bound as $x \rightarrow + \infty$

With $\beta = \frac{1}{3},$ here is a nice graph for $x > 0.$

[image]

Comment: well, it is positive infinity, right?

Comment: @HunterDJohny do you know a way to prove that?

Comment: I know that the numerator grows faster than the denominater, but i cannot say that the numerator is always bigger, so i'm not sure.

Comment: @HunterDJohny LHospitals rule. Also, if $\beta$ is small enough, the ratio will be smaller than $1$ for some values of $x,$ but then grow without bound as $x$ increases still more

Comment: Is there any way to proove it without using the derivation?